# Losing executors when saving parquet file

Tags: pyspark, parquet

I have loaded a dataset which is just around ~ 20 GB in size - the cluster has ~ 1TB available so memory shouldn't be an issue imho.

It is no problem for me to save the original data which consists only of strings:

```py
df_data.write.parquet(os.path.join(DATA_SET_BASE, 'concatenated.parquet'), mode='overwrite')
```

However, as I transform the data:

```py
df_transformed = df_data.drop('bri').join(
    df_data[['docId', 'bri']].rdd\
        .map(lambda x: (x.docId, json.loads(x.bri)) 
             if x.bri is not None else (x.docId, dict()))\
        .toDF()\
        .withColumnRenamed('_1', 'docId')\
        .withColumnRenamed('_2', 'bri'),
    ['dokumentId']
)
```

and then save it:

```py
df_transformed.parquet(os.path.join(DATA_SET_BASE, 'concatenated.parquet'), mode='overwrite')
```

The log output will tell me that the memory limit was exceeded:

```
18/03/08 10:23:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 17.0 in stage 18.3 (TID 2866, worker06.hadoop.know-center.at): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 40 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 15.2 GB of 13.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
18/03/08 10:23:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 29.0 in stage 18.3 (TID 2878, worker06.hadoop.know-center.at): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 40 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 15.2 GB of 13.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
18/03/08 10:23:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 65.0 in stage 18.3 (TID 2914, worker06.hadoop.know-center.at): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 40 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 15.2 GB of 13.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Even setting the executor's memory to 60GB RAM each does not solve the problem.

So, obviously the problem comes with the transformation. Any idea what exactly causes this problem?

Comment: Did [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49177210/5858851) to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173600/transforming-a-column-and-update-the-dataframe/49177210) help here?

Comment: @pault Well, actually I think the problem is with one of the columns in the `DataFrame` - there's one column called `volltext` which appears to be the problem. This column contains the largest amount of data (yet it's still below 20GB) - but for some reason if I don't remove it I am getting this exception.