# Transforming a column and update the DataFrame

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, what I'm doing below is I drop a column `A` from a `DataFrame` because I want to apply a transformation (here I just `json.loads` a JSON string) and replace the old column with the transformed one. After the transformation I just join the two resulting data frames.

```py
df = df_data.drop('A').join(
    df_data[['ID', 'A']].rdd\
        .map(lambda x: (x.ID, json.loads(x.A)) 
             if x.A is not None else (x.ID, None))\
        .toDF()\
        .withColumnRenamed('_1', 'ID')\
        .withColumnRenamed('_2', 'A'),
    ['ID']
)
```

The thing I dislike about this is of course the overhead I'm faced because I had to do the `withColumnRenamed` operations.

With pandas All I'd do something like this:

```py
pdf = pd.DataFrame([json.dumps([0]*np.random.randint(5,10)) for i in range(10)], columns=['A'])
pdf.A = pdf.A.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
pdf
```

but the following does not work in pyspark:

```py
df.A = df[['A']].rdd.map(lambda x: json.loads(x.A))
```

So is there an easier way than what I'm doing in my first code snipped?

Comment: `.toDF()` can take positional arguments for column names. If you're concerned about the calls to `withColumnRenamed()`, you can do `toDF(["ID", "A"])` to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you need to drop the column and do the join. The following code should<sup>*</sup> be equivalent to what you posted:

```python
cols = df_data.columns
df = df_data.rdd\
    .map(
        lambda row: tuple(
            [row[c] if c != 'A' else (json.loads(row[c]) if row[c] is not None else None) 
             for c in cols]
        )
    )\
    .toDF(cols)
```

<sup>*</sup>*I haven't actually tested this code, but I think this should work.*

But to answer your general question, you can transform a column in-place using `withColumn()`.

```python
df = df_data.withColumn("A", my_transformation_function("A").alias("A"))
```

Where `my_transformation_function()` can be a `udf` or a `pyspark sql function`.

Comment: Ah, well the second option is definitely what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From what i could understand, is it something like this you are trying to achieve?

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import json

json_convert = F.udf(lambda x: json.loads(x) if x is not None else None)

cols = df_data.columns
df = df_data.select([json_convert(F.col('A')).alias('A')] + \
                    [col for col in cols if col != 'A'])
```

Comment: Is that the simplest thing we can do?

Comment: i am afraid yes :)

Comment: No, you can do something simpler: `df = df_data.withColumn("A", json_convert(F.col('A')).alias('A'))`

Comment: I agree with @pault Didnt know how i missed that

Comment: Ah, that is great. Thank you mayank but I'll accept @pault s answer since it is definitely simpler. But thanks to both of you!